# matlab: different entropy values for the same image with different data type

Tags: image, matlab, double, entropy, uint

given an image I of type `uint8` in matlab

```
entropy(I)
```

gives me a very different result from

```
entropy(im2double(I))
```

(e.g. 6.98 in the first case, 0.51 in the second case)
why the datatype changes this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read an image using `imread`, your image is read into a `uint` m-by-n-by-3 array. Depending on the image format, 16 or fewer bits per color plane (red, green, blue) are used in order to store image pixels.

`uint8` (unsigned 8 bits integer) is a numeric format for integers that allows a minimum value of `0` and a maximum value of `255`. `uint16` (unsigned 16 bits integer) is a numeric format for integers that allows a minimum value of `0` and a maximum value of `65535`. When you convert these numerical formats into `double`, you are basically dividing them by their maximum value:

```
% Pseudocode

uint8 val = 127;
double val_new = val / 255.0d; % 0.49803921568627450980392156862745

uint16 val = 42133;
double val_new = val / 65535.0d; % 0.64290836957351033798733501182574
```

The `double` numerical format is normally used to store very big (64 bits) floating-point values that need to ensure a high precision. This means that your `uint` values will be converted into `0.something` values, where `something` represents a (variable but potentially) huge amount of digits.

Since the **Shannon Entropy** (more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))) is defined as the average amount of information produced by a stochastic source of data... your result is easily explained: you are feeding the `entropy` function with a higher degree of information (greater amount of bytes, greater amount of digits, greater amount of information).

Comment: this seems to me an entropy-lie... the information is the same, is just another format to represent it. yes, I have more bits, but I think that a lot of these (MSBs) are zeros...so I could think that uint8 entropy is more "accurate" respect to double format....what do you think about it?

Comment: I kinda agree with your assumption. If I was given the choice, I would analyze the entropy with the minimum necessary amount of data needed to represent the targeted stochastic information. But don't oversimplify the mechanics behind floating-point numerical formats... they are much more complex than what you think (on the point of view of their binary structure).

Comment: sure, it's just an approximation to understand better this strange behavior ;) thank you!